# excluding null values from field splitting

Tags: vba, split, null

I have an old database table (Name) with fields like this:

ID Names
1  a,b,c,d
2  a,b
3  e,f,g
4
5  s,t

And as long as there are no NUlls, as I have created in record 4, the following code

```
Sub SplitNames()
Dim strNames() As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSql As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Name")

Do While Not rs.EOF
ID = rs!ID
strNames = Split(rs!names, ",")
For i = LBound(strNames) To UBound(strNames)
strSql = "Insert into name2 (ID, Names) values (" & ID & ", '" &      strNames(i) & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
Next i
rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

works fine to parse these comma separated values into rows of a second Table, Name2:

ID Name
1  a
1  b
1  c
1  d
2  a
2  b

etc,

But when it gets to a NUll value, of which there are many, I get compile errors here:

```
strNames = Split(rs!names, ",")
```

so I tried this to specify a condition, Do, only for not null values:

```
Sub SplitNames()
Dim strNames() As String
Dim ID As Integer
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSql As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Name")

If Not IsNull(rs!names) Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
ID = rs!ID
strNames = Split(rs!names, ",")
For i = LBound(strNames) To UBound(strNames)
strSql = "Insert into Name2 (ID, Names) values (" & ID & ", '" &  strNames(i) & "')"
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
Next i
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If 

End Sub
```

Again, this works until I have a Null value.  Same line of code.

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

These lines are in the wrong order:

```
If Not IsNull(rs!names) Then
    Do While Not rs.EOF
```

This means you only check for Null on the very first record and don't check on the other records. Try this instead:

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If Not IsNull(rs!names) Then
```

**edit:** the end of the macro also needs to be altered like this to avoid an infinite loop:

```
        Next i
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also switched the Loop and End If statements to avoid a Loop without a Do error, but that seems to created an endless process, so I am still doing something wrong.

Comment: I've added how to re-write the end of the macro to my answer

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by creating a select query and setting it as the record set;  Not really a programming solution but it works.